# Allowed fields must be specified for model how to fix the error?

Tags: codeigniter-4

I am new to codeigniter 4 user and have faced these types errors please any one help to me... How to fix the error.

`CodeIgniter\Database\Exceptions\Data Exception Allowed fields must be specified for model: App\Models\Student Model`

Comment: Could you please show us your `App\Models\StudentModel` class?

Comment: I will find the issue .. Thanks for your response

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand there are 2 possible solutions:

- do not use the `Allowed fields` functionality (`$protectFields = false`)
- specify the `Allowed fields` for every model

in a model

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

class The_specific_model extends Model
{
    // THESE LINES
    protected $protectFields = false;
    protected $allowedFields = [
        'name',
        'language',
        /* All other fields */
    ];
}
```

in a controller

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Models\The_specific_model;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class The_specific_controller extends BaseController
{
    public function initController(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        parent::initController($request, $response, $logger);

        // THESE LINES
        $model = new The_specific_model();
        $model->protect(false);
    }
}
```

Sources:

- [Forum CodeIgniter](https://forum.codeigniter.com/post-376104.html)
- [BaseModel.php line 94 - $allowedFields](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/develop/system/BaseModel.php#L94)
- [BaseModel.php line 157 - $protectFields](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/develop/system/BaseModel.php#L157)

Answer (score 0):

look at my model
works for me fine

```
<?php namespace Modules\App\Models;

use Modules\App\Entities\CourseCategoryEntity;
use CodeIgniter\Model;
use Modules\Shared\Models\Aggregation;

class CourseCategoryModel extends Aggregation
{


    /**
     * table name
     */
    protected $primaryKey = "id";
    protected $table = "course_category";

    /**
     * allowed Field
     */
    protected $allowedFields = [
        'name',
        'language'
    ];


    protected $returnType = CourseCategoryEntity::class;
    protected $validationRules = [
        'name' => 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[255]',
        'language' => 'required|min_length[1]|max_length[255]',


    ];
    protected $useSoftDeletes = false;
    protected $validationMessages = [];
    protected $skipValidation = false;


}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: good . thanks for your response . i am also change my model structure and it's works well.

Comment: your well come i m fan of ci4 its great php framework  :-)